# Why it tells me to convert time to int? the format of time is XX:XX, what this type of this variable should be?

Tags: java, variables, time

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class filmboxoffice {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String [] filmname = new String [4];
        String [] filmtime = new String [4];
        String name;
        String time;
        int result;

        for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
        {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the film on Screen "+i+" today?");
            result = i;
            time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What time does it start?");

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Screen "+ result +": "+"   "+filmtime [time]);

    }
}
```

Error Stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

at filmboxoffice.main(filmboxoffice.java:22)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? when you say `filmtime[time]`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this expression:

```
filmtime [time]
```

`filmtime` is an [*array*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) - and arrays are always accessed by index, which is an `int`. `time` is a variable of type `String`, so you can't use it as an array index.

Perhaps you want a `Map<String, String>`, or better yet using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net), a `Map<LocalTime, Film>`?

Actually, reading this again, it looks like should actually have something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Screen "+ i +": "+"   "+filmtime[i]);
}
```

... after populating it, of course. (You're currently ignoring the value of `time` after prompting the user for it.)

Note that arrays in Java start at 0, so a `new String[4]` has valid indexes of 0, 1, 2 and 3, so your current loop is going to throw an exception - and it's not clear what `result` is meant to be, given that it will *always* be 4 at the end of your current loop.

Comment: @vikiiii it will still be an honour to upvote him. Come on man, he's a legend on SO and infact, in the world.

Comment: yh I went to his page and I was blowed away, amazing

Comment: @vikiiii maybe man. I did probably. I am waiting for Bjarne Stroustrup to show up actually.

Comment: I wanted to answer this question. The minute I saw JonSkeet posting I backed the fsck off.

Comment: @vikiiii I mean, look at the other poor folks who posted.

Comment: You still can if you have a better solution.

Comment: @JonSkeet he's trying to index using a `String` instead of an `int` @ `filmtime [time]`

Comment: @PrototypeStark: Yes, exactly. That's why it doesn't work. Will edit to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Because variable time is String typed. You need to parse it to Integer to get access to that element of the array, could be something like:

```
filmtime[Integer.parseInt(time)]
```

And your error would be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You have     String [] filmtime = new String [4];

So, in your code, filmtime [time] : time should be an in type, i.e., the index in Array.

However, your time variable is String type.

try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Screen "+ result +": "+"   "+filmtime [result]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `time` as `String` and trying to use at `index` for array element. Array indexes are integer values starting from `0` to refer the first element in the array.

Please use correct index element in `filmtime [time]` statement.

I suspect you wanted to use `result` instead as `filmtime [result]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=1; i<5; i++)
 {
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the film on Screen "+i+" today?");
            result = i;
            filmname[i-1] = new String(name);
            time = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What time does it start?");

            filmtime[i-1] = new String(time); 
 }
```

Judging from your question, I think this is what you meant to do.

And this one should be: `

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Screen "+ (i + 1) +": "+ filmname[i]+ " "+filmtime[i];
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet RFC? Please? I tried to understand what he was trying to do.